# Monitoring WSO2 IS logins/loguts, using WSO2 bam

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to monitor the logins/logouts (and perhaps other admin services) from a WSO2 Identity Server to WSO2 Buisness Activity Monitor. I found a couple of articles on how to do it, using an WSO2 ESB or/and WSO2 AS. However I would like to do it without the ESB/AS.

Is this possible? And if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic way of monitoring a server by BAM is through a custom data agent. Follow [1] for referring how to write a BAM data agent. You can write a data agent to monitor WSO2 Identity Server (IS) which publishes events from IS to BAM.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM230/Data+Publisher

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've managed to write a custom data agent. However I am not sure how to hook the custom data agent to the identity server login/logout event. Do I have create my own patch for the identity server with the custom agent in the login logic or there is easier way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the articles explaining how to configure log4j logging to log to the BAM server for storage in Cassandra. They are applicable to the IS server as well since the IS is, just as all WSO2 products, based on the same base product called 'Carbon'.

If you specifically want to log only the login/logout events and not any additional logging you could adjust the appender in such a way that only the following class will log to that appender (as shown here: [log4j: Log output of a specific class to a specific appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763740/log4j-log-output-of-a-specific-class-to-a-specific-appender)):

log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil=INFO, LOGEVENT
log4j.additivity.org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil=false