# Separating rabbitMQ messaging logs into a different log file

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, rabbitmq

I am working on a Spring Hibernate project with Spring AMQP RabbitMQ implementation for messaging. The rabbitmq configuration is in a separate xml which gets imported into the root application context. The rabbitmq listener receiver polls the queue every second. The important log messages get buried under the truckloads of DEBUG-level polling messages being dumped into the log file.

```
2015-10-11 18:12:02.0031 DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer – Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-p4K9s4EoXAbxKWufSzX_-w]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-10-11 18:12:03.0032 DEBUG SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer – Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-p4K9s4EoXAbxKWufSzX_-w]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

Is there a way to separate out this polling logging into a different file or stop it from polluting the logs?

I am using log4j for logging; Configuration below.

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxxx.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS} %p %t %c \u2013 %m%n


# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this statements (I omitted the full configuration for the second file logger `file2`)

```
log4j.appender.file2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file2.File=C:\\Users\\xxx\\other.log
...

log4j.logger.org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer=DEBUG, file2
log4j.additivity.org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer=false
```

this will put the log entries from `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer` to an other log file.

---

If you do not want to have this logs at all, then use

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer=WARN
```

instead.

@see: [log4j: Log output of a specific class to a specific appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763740/log4j-log-output-of-a-specific-class-to-a-specific-appender)