# I need separate my apllication logging from the server.log

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

I want my application has its own logging configuration. I want to separate my logs from the server.log file. i am using jboss 7 and log4j. And please tell me how i configure my jboss 7 with my log4j and using struts2 framwork.

Answer (score 0):

Read up about Log4J appenders. The general idea is you'd have an appender that would capture all logging under a specific package, preventing it from being outputted into server.log

Here is a reasonable answer that would help - [log4j: Log output of a specific class to a specific appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763740/log4j-log-output-of-a-specific-class-to-a-specific-appender)