# log4j issue: redirect logg to many files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Actually i am using log4j 1.2 with an xml configration file;
Is it possible to redirect the log of each class in a specified file; i want to logg in 3 files.

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" >
    <!-- <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />  -->
    <param name="File" value="log/archive.log" />
     <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>                                   
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender" >
        <!-- <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />  -->
        <param name="File" value="log/check.log" />
         <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>                                   
    </appender>


 <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />    
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1}: %m [%L]%n"  />
            </layout>
</appender> 
<logger name="org.apache.axis">
    <level value="DEBUG"/> 
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value ="DEBUG"/> 

     <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
</root>
```

Comment: you can file solution with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763740/log4j-log-output-of-a-specific-class-to-a-specific-appender/38040074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can file solution with [log4j: Log output of a specific class to a specific appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763740/log4j-log-output-of-a-specific-class-to-a-specific-appender/38040074)